# php, error in class when I use $this->

Tags: php

I get this error in my code when I use `$this->`

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/u506382626/public_html/s1/arrays.php on line 21

I though that is how you access current objects variables, isn't it?

This is my code. I'm trying to make an array that has bigger values for every index but instead of index I use function at. Is it possible to overload operator[] in php and how do you do it?

Hope someone knows what's the problem.

```
<?php

class zArray {
    public $change = 1.165;

    public $lenght;
    private $vars = array();
    public $name;
    public $percent = false;

    public function __construct($values) {
        for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
            $vars[$i] = $values[$i];
        }
        $lenght = $values[5];
        $name = $values[6];
        $percent = $values[7];
    }

    public function at($i) {
        $newchange = $this->$change;
        for ( $i-- ; $i; $i-- )
            $newChange *= $this->$change;

        $newVars = $this->$vars;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
            $newVars[$i] *= $newChange;
        }
        if ($percent) $newVars[4] /= $newChange;
        else $newVars[4] *= $newChange;

        return $newVars;
    }
};

$buildings = array(
    new zArray(85, 70, 65, 2, 100, 'Castle', true)
);

$try = $buildings[0]->at(3);



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this: `$this->$change`. The second `$` sign (ie the one on `$change`) is wrong. To access the object property, you should just specify `$this->change`.

I can see how the error message is confusing though.

The reason for the specific error message you're getting is that `$this->$change` **is** valid syntax. What it means is take the value of the local variable `$change`, and find the property of the object who's name is that value.

So if you had `$change = "name";`, then you would find that `$this->$change` would work, and it would get the value of the `name` property. ie it would be equivalent of `$this->name`.

This is similar to using the `$$` syntax for variable variables.

And that leads us to explaining what the error message is trying to tell you: Since in reality you don't have a local `$change` variable, PHP sees it as being blank. So when you do `$this->$change`, and the `$change` part gives an empty string, PHP quite rightly complains that you are trying to access an empty property.

Hope that helps explain things. The error message can be confusing, but understanding what it's trying to tell you does make it easier to spot what's going on.

Comment: now that is a full answer. I knew it was a little thing, but since I newer made classes in php I had no idea what it might be.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access the variable like this

```
$this->$change; //wrong
```

Try this one

```
$this->change;
```

Comment: Additionaly to this, I'd say you shouldn't confuse static variables with dynamic ones. So `Class::$staticVar` but `$class->dynamycVar`